# Any reason why Java shouldn't allow generic type declarations on a variable declaration?

Tags: java, generics, language-design

Suppose we have a class like this:

```
public class xx {

    public interface Foo<T> {
        T getValue();
        void setValue(T value);
    }

    public void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<?>> foos) {
        for (Foo<?> foo : foos)
            foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
    }
}
```

It will fail to compile even though intuitively it seems like it "should":

```
xx.java:10: setValue(capture#496 of ?) in xx.Foo<capture#496 of ?> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)
        foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
```

The reason is that `foo` does not have a bound generic type, so the compiler doesn't "know" that the output of `foo.getValue()` is compatible with the input of `foo.setValue()`.

So to fix this you have to create a new method just for the purpose of binding the generic type parameter in the `for()` loop:

```
public class xx {

    public interface Foo<T> {
        T getValue();
        void setValue(T value);
    }

    public void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<?>> foos) {
        for (Foo<?> foo : foos)
            this.resetFoo(foo);
    }
    
    // stupid extra method here just to bind <T>
    private <T> void resetFoo(Foo<T> foo) {
        foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
    }
}
```

This has always annoyed me. Plus, it seems like there can be a simple solution.

My question: **Is there any "good" reason why the java language shouldn't be extended to allow generic type declarations on variable declarations?** For example:

```
public class xx {

    public interface Foo<T> {
        T getValue();
        void setValue(T value);
    }

    public void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<?>> foos) {
        for (Foo<?> foo : foos) {
            final <T> Foo<T> typedFoo = foo;
            foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

or, more concisely in this case of a `for()` loop:

```
public class xx {

    public interface Foo<T> {
        T getValue();
        void setValue(T value);
    }

    public void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<?>> foos) {
        for (<T> Foo<?> foo : foos)
            foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if some compiler wizard can explain why this would either be too hard, or can (and should) be done.

**EDIT:**

In response to this suggested solution:

```
public <T> void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<T>> foos) {
    for (Foo<T> foo : foos) {
        foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
    }
}
```

This method signature doesn't allow `Foo`s with various generic types to be reset together. In other words, trying to pass in an `Iterable<Foo<?>>` causes a compile error.

[This example](http://ideone.com/uUfDub) demonstrates the problem:

```
public static class FooImpl<T> implements Foo<T> {
    
    private T value;
    
    public FooImpl(T value) { this.value = value; }
    
    @Override public T getValue() { return value; }
    
    @Override public void setValue(T value) { this.value = value; }
}

public static <T> void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<T>> foos) {
    for (Foo<T> foo : foos) {
        foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    final Foo<Object> objFoo = new FooImpl<>(new Object());
    final Foo<Integer> numFoo = new FooImpl<>(new Integer(42));
    final Foo<String> strFoo = new FooImpl<>("asdf");
    
    List<Foo<?>> foos = new ArrayList<>(3);
    foos.add(objFoo);
    foos.add(numFoo);
    foos.add(strFoo);
    
    resetFoos(foos); // compile error
    
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

The compile error reads:

> method `resetFoos` cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: `Iterable<Foo<T>>`
>
> found: `List<Foo<?>>`
>
> reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) `T` exist so that argument type `List<Foo<?>>` conforms to formal parameter type `Iterable<Foo<T>>`
> where `T` is a type-variable:
> `T extends Object` declared in method `<T>resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<T>>)`

(using sun-jdk-1.7.0_10 via ideone.com)

Comment: Why not use `public <T> void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<T>> foos) {...}`?

Comment: Folks, `Iterable<Foo<T>> != Iterable<Foo<?>>`

Comment: @Archie What's your point? We're wondering *why* you don't want to use that solution.

Comment: Because it doesn't solve the case of `Iterable<Foo<?>>`. Not all the `Foo` objects in the `Iterable` can be assumed to have the same generic type. This situation does occur in real life.

Comment: @Archie I see what you mean. I've updated your question with an example of the problem you're implying. In the future please make the effort to do that yourself so the issue is clear to everyone.

Comment: I thought by putting my question in boldface I was making clear what the actual question was but apparently not! :)

Comment: @Archie You have to understand that when you ask a *language design* question, it's a) going to be hard for anyone but the language designers to definitely answer and therefore b) naturally cause people to question your premise and offer workarounds to solve the underlying issue. For that reason you have to be ready to "defend" your premise to commenters/answerers, like with the example I edited in.

Comment: You have a good point. I'll try to include more digression deflection devices next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, type variables can only currently have two scopes in Java: 1) class scope, or 2) method scope. You're asking, why not allow another scope -- scope of a local block of code (in this case, the inside of a for loop.

Yes, in some cases this would be helpful. And it would be not too hard to add it to the language. However, these are pretty rare cases, and is more likely to confuse people than help. Also, a relatively simple and effective workaround exists, as you have already discovered -- move that local block scope to a private helper function, which can then use a method-scope type variable:

```
public void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<?>> foos) {
    for (Foo<?> foo : foos) {
        resetFoo(foo);
    }
}

private <T> void resetFoo(Foo<T> foo) {
    foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
}
```

Yes, this might make the code less efficient by making extra method calls, but that is a minor concern.

Comment: Thank you for restating my question more clearly. BTW it's not performance that is the problem in my opinion, it's code verbosity/clarity.

Comment: without some concrete details, it's unclear what you and Archie are proposing, and why you guys think it'll be easy. but the workaround through method invocation depends on type inference in method invocation expressions, there's nothing like that for a local scope.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu: it actually depends on capture

Comment: capture happens regardless. the key is to convert the undenotable type variable introduced by capture conversion to a denotable type variable through method invocation type inference.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu: yes, whatever type inference and capture conversion is happening when you call the helper method, why can't we add a new construct to the language that does the exact same conversion when initializing a local variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `resetFoos` method itself generic:

```
public <T> void resetFoos(Iterable<Foo<T>> foos) {
    for ( Foo<T> foo : foos)
        foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
}
```

That way the compiler knows that the `T` from `foo.getValue()` is the same `T` for `foo.setValue()`.

That's just the workaround.  I do not know why the compiler doesn't let you declare generics at a variable level such as `final <T> Foo<T> typedFoo = foo;`; I just know that you can't declare it at the variable level.  However, here, the method level is sufficient.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: but then every Foo has to have the same type parameter

Comment: @PaulBellora - Yes, at first I thought the question was How do I work around this compiler error.  It's not a full answer.

Comment: @GeoffReedy - The method is generic.  So, `<T>` doesn't have to be the same for every invocation.  You could call `resetFoos` with `foos` being a `Iterable<Foo<MyClass1>>` then you could also call `resetFoos` with `foos` being a `Iterable<Foo<MyClass2>>` and it would work.

Comment: @rgettman, I mean that every Foo in the iterable needs the same type parameter

Comment: @GeoffReedy `T` isn't bounded - it could be `Object`. But to your point the method should really take `Iterable<? extends Foo<T>>`.

Comment: Sorry for repeating myself on the page, but for any skimmers -- it's worth pointing out that the `<T>` in this code block shadows, and thus has nothing to do with, the `T` of `Foo<T>`. Would probably be best to use a different name for the generic altogether, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @yshavit The `T` in the `resetFoos` method doesn't shadow the `T` of the `Foo` type per se, because the `resetFoos` method is outside the `Foo` interface.

Comment: @matts Right you are! I misread the OP's code myself, and thought the top-level class was `Foo<T>` (not `xx`).

Comment: Friendly -1. See my update to the question, which demonstrates what I think the OP's issue is. I think this also validates what @GeoffReedy is talking about.

Comment: @PaulBellora: If I have an `Iterable<Foo<?>>`, it cannot be passed to this method. I think this is what Geoff Reedy is saying.

Comment: @newacct Yeah, I'm on the same page now - in fact I edited the question with an example showing that.

Comment: There are a few cases where free-typed generic variables could be helpful even without reified types, but probably not enough to justify the effort to implement them.  Consider, for example, a method which takes parameters of types T1 and T2, both of which constrained to Intf1 and Intf2.  It wishes to copy one of the parameters, and then later call some other method which takes a generic parameter constrained to Intf1 and Intf2.  There may be no single type from which both parameter types are derived, and which implements both interfaces. Even if a generic variable would be useful there...

Comment: ...and would in theory be statically-verifiably typesafe, however, such situations don't arise that often; further, if one wanted to allow such situations to be handled better, a more generally-useful way of accomplishing it would be to allow the definition of "duck-typable" composite interfaces, such that if one declared a DTCI of type `Intf1and2` comprised of Intf1 and Intf2, any type implementing both interfaces would be considered an implementation of `Intf1and2`.  If one could do that, one would simply use a field of type `Intf1and2`.

Answer (score 2):

It probably could be done, possibly with some edge cases. But really, the reason it's not done is simply that the JLS people stopped short of doing it.

A type system isn't going to be able to infer *everything* about your program. It'll do a bunch, but there'll always be some place where a compiler/type checker won't know something that you the human can prove. So, the people who design compilers and type checkers have to decide how far to go in terms of inferring and being clever -- and no matter where they stop, someone will always be able to pose a question like this one: "why didn't they go this extra step?"

My guess -- and it's only a guess -- is that this inference didn't make it because of some mix of (a) it's easy to work around (as rgettman shows), (b) it complicates the language, (b.1) it introduces tricky edge cases, some of which may even be incompatible with other features of the language, (c) the designers of the JLS didn't feel they had time to work on it.

Comment: I'm not asking the compiler to infer anything. I'm asking the compiler to let me tell it something.

Comment: The usual rule for generics is that if you have a `Foo<T>` with a method `setFoo(T foo)`, then you can't pass anything but `null` to `Foo<?>`. This rule is absolutely necessary in general, but you're asking the compiler to make an exception to that rule in the specific case where the non-null argument comes directly from `getFoo()`.

Comment: You're still not understanding what I'm asking. `foo.setValue(foo.getValue())` works fine - if the generic type of `foo` is bound. My example shows how to do that by creating a new method that gives the type a bound name. I'm simply wondering why the JLS doesn't provide for a more convenient way to bind it that doesn't involve having to write a new method.

Comment: No, I _am_ understanding. But my point is that the JLS has to draw the line somewhere. If `foo.setValue(foo.getValue())` works, what about `Object o = foo.getValue(); foo.setValue(o);`? It would after all be the same trick to allow the first as the second, and it's a similar trick to Java 7's rethrow improvements (where the compiler "downcasts" `Exception` in certain cases), so there's precedent. Where does it end? No matter where you stop being clever, there'll always be a slightly-less-trivial example that you could point to and say "if you allow A, why not A'?"

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just don't understand why you don't understand me :) Maybe I should have qualified previous comment by saying: `foo.setValue(foo.getValue())` works _but only when foo has type `Foo<T>` instead of `Foo<?>`_. I'm *not* suggesting changing any of that behavior; I'm asking for a more convenient way to declare a `T` to bind to, creating a new `Foo<T>` typed variable from a `Foo<?>` one, without creating a new method.

Comment: Again, I do understand you. Your question essentially boils down to, "if this is so obviously true, then why can't the language help me help it figure that out -- in a more convenient way than this extra `resetFoo` method?" And my point is that no matter how much the language helps you help it, at some point there'll always be something that you can easily prove but have to jump through some hoops to convince the language. The language designers have to stop somewhere, and each new convenience has a cost to the language in terms of added complexity, edge cases, development time, etc.

Comment: Indeed I agree with your general point, but (and you keep saying this) I'm not asking the compiler to _infer_ anything new or help me _figure anything out_ that I don't already know. I'm simply asking for a more concise way to _tell it_ what I do already know, using a declaration on a _variable_ that is _perfectly analogous to the delcarations on method parameters that it already supports_. In other words, the compiler already handles the same situation elsewhere so "in theory" this addition should not be very hard.

Answer (score 2):

Every change to java language will be very hard.

Your example is not really about the need of a type variable. The compiler already creates a type variable through wildcard capture, it's just that the type variable isn't available to the programmer. There might be several remedies

1. let the programmer access the type variable. This isn't an easy task. We need to invent some bizzare syntax and semantics. The weirdness and complexity may not justify the benefit.
2. shared capture conversion. Right now, every expression goes through capture conversion separately. The spec does not recognize that `foo` is `foo` so the two expressions should share the same capture conversion. It is doable on some simple cases, for example, an effectively final local variable should be capture-converted only once, not on every access.
3. inferred variable type - `var foo2 = foo;` The type of `foo2`is inferred from the right hand side, which actually undergoes capture conversion first, therefore `foo2`'s type will be `Foo<x> for some x`, with a new type variable x (still undenotable). Or use `var` directly on `foo` - `for(var foo: foos)`. Inferred variable type is a mature/tested technique, and its benefit is far broader than solving this problem. So I'll vote for this one. It might be coming in java 9, if we can live that long.

Comment: It would be even better if the compiler would infer things. I'm asking for something simpler (I think), just a way for me to declare and bind a type in a variable declaration in exactly the same way you can already do so in a method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the statement in question:

```
foo.setValue(foo.getValue());
```

the two occurrences of `?` can (as far as the compiler knows) be bound to different types. It may seem silly that the compiler can't figure out that one `?` (that is returned by `getValue()`) isn't the same as the `?` that is expected in `setValue`. But in other situations, the result is not so clear-cut. The language requires that type parameters be named the same if they are supposed to be the same.

A fine workaround is provided in [rgettman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15887335/535871).

Comment: I'm not asking for an explanation of the current behavior. Nor am I asking for a workaround (which doesn't work by the way).

Comment: @Archie - It's not clear exactly what you are asking. However, I've modified my answer to address what I think you might be driving at.

Comment: See my update to the question in case you want to edit/respond further.

Comment: I don't think you're right. `Iterable<Foo<?>>` means "iteration of `Foo`s, each of which has an unknown generic type". Otherwise how do you explain why this compiles cleanly (which it does): `HashSet<Set<?>> set = new HashSet<Set<?>>(); set.add(new HashSet<Float>()); set.add(new HashSet<Integer>());`.

Comment: "In particular, Iterable<Foo<?>> means "an Iterable of Foo objects with a fixed but unknown parameterized type"." This is incorrect. It is exactly an iterable whose elements can be Foo of different parameterized types.

Comment: Agreed with @newacct - I think a large source of the confusion on this post stems from the fact that the `?` in `Iterable<Foo<?>>` is a *nested* wildcard.

Comment: @newacct - You're right, of course. I've removed the offending analysis from my answer.